# Tor on windows Xp not work

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows

Why Tor is not running anymore on Windows XP?

> torbrowser-install-6.0.5_en-US.exe

In previous version after 10-20 restarting browser was loaded, but now it is not loading. No appear this screen

[image]

After press tor button [image] appears only Firefox without tor button, tor button cannot be enabled from settings.

[image]

Only tor browser starts after first installiation or reinstallation.

So question is:

1. Which command is sending after first instalattion to start Tor Browser to get this?
   [image]
2. how to run Tor Browser on Windows Xp? To get this

[image]

After moving Tor folder to new location directly to c:\ i have error

[image]

On pressing "restart tor" shortly appears Tor status windows and gone.

And also 0 logs

[image]

After closing this windows appears

[image]

Torrc file contents

```
LearnCircuitBuildTimeout 0
CircuitBuildTimeout 1
DataDirectory "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor"
GeoIPFile "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip"
GeoIPv6File "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6"
HiddenServiceStatistics 0
MaxCircuitDirtiness 10
NewCircuitPeriod 1
StrictNodes 1
Log debug file "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\debug.Log"
Log "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\debug.Log"
```

Comment: Do you have a log? Can you edit your question and add the log, please?

Comment: Here you can find the answer https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#Logs

Comment: There are no logs at all

Comment: By default no logs, you have to enable by changing your torrc file. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Problem was in Torrc file

must be

`LearnCircuitBuildTimeout 0 
CircuitBuildTimeout 1 
DataDirectory "C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor 
GeoIPFile C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip 
GeoIPv6File C:\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\geoip6 HiddenServiceStatistics 0 MaxCircuitDirtiness 10

NewCircuitPeriod 1

StrictNodes 1`